# Cannot resolve Oracle connection with Entity Framework tool

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-5, odp.net

I'm trying to learn and implement Entity FW in my project (Using `Oracle 11g`).
I'm trying to connect to my project using `ODP.NET` data source and getting the next error:

> "ORA:12154:TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

[image: A screen shoot of what I'm trying to do, with the error showing]

I looked into stuckoverflow and see that the say to see if the `PATH` variable is configured correctly and I see there this:

```
C:\app\USER\oracle\bin;C:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\client_1;
```

after all these I check the my `TNSNAMES.ORA` file and see that in my 2 `HOME` folders there is the same `TNSNAMES.ORA` file and the Instance I'm trying to connect too is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do below mentioned check list for solve this issue.

- If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):
- Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
- Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
- Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
- Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.
- If you are using directory naming:
- Verify that "LDAP" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
- Verify that the LDAP directory server is up and that it is accessible.
- Verify that the net service name or database name used as the connect identifier is configured in the directory.
- Verify that the default context being used is correct by specifying a fully qualified net service name or a full LDAP DN as the connect identifier
- If you are using easy connect naming:
- Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
- Make sure the host, port and service name specified are correct.
- Try enclosing the connect identifier in quote marks. See the Oracle Net Services Administrators Guide or the Oracle operating system specific guide for more information on naming.

For more information check 
[**Oracle® Database Net Services Administrator's Guide**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/toc.htm) under "Oracle Net Connections"

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: 10x a lot :) now the connection succeed but, when I hit the filter tab I can't see any of my tables (or any other relevant data for that matter) even I hit the OK button nothing happen. have any idea?

Comment: @SigmaOmega Glad to hear that it helped.Yes that issue may be solve If you can close the visual studio and open again your project.Try that.May be that is the solution.B'cos sometimes cache data is troubling the Ui.